# Showing that the cofactor expansion is skew symmetric

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A$ be an arbitrary $n\times n$ matrix. I'm trying to show that the function$$d_j(A) = \sum_{i=1}^n a_{ij}C_{ij}, j = 1,2,\dots,n$$ is equal to the determinant function, where $C_{ij} = (-1)^{i + j}\det(A_{ij})$ is the determinant of that minor of $A$ whose $i$th row and $j$th column has been removed, and $a_{ij}$ is the $(i, j)$th element of the matrix $A$. So far I've been able to show that $d$ is multilinear, but currently I'm stuck on the proof that $d$ is skew symmetric. Namely, suppose that $$r_1, r_2,\dots,r_{l-1},r_l,r_{l+1},\dots,r_{k-1},r_k,r_{k+1},\dots,r_n$$ are the row vectors of A for $1\leq l < k \leq n$.

Then for $A'$ whose row vectors are $r_1, r_2,\dots,r_{l-1},r_k,r_{l+1},\dots,r_{k-1},r_l,r_{k+1},\dots,r_n$ it holds that $$\tag{1} d_j(A') = \sum_{i=1}^n(-1)^{i + j}a'_{ij}\det(A'_{ij}) =$$$$\tag{1} = \left(\sum_{i=1: i \notin\{l, k\}}^n(-1)^{i + j}a'_{ij}\det(A'_{ij})\right) + (-1)^{j + l}a'_{lj}\det(A'_{lj}) + (-1)^{j + k}a'_{kj}\det(A'_{kj}).$$

Since the $l$th and $k$th rows have inverted positions and the index $i$ does not equal $l$ nor $k$ in the first summand of (1), it follows from the skew symmetry of determinant that $$\left(\sum_{i=1: i \notin\{l, k\}}^n(-1)^{i + j}a'_{ij}\det(A'_{ij})\right) = -\left(\sum_{i=1: i \notin\{l, k\}}^n(-1)^{i + j}a_{ij}\det(A_{ij})\right)$$ i.e. we can just swap the $l$th and $k$th rows. In the other two summands of (1), the $l$th and $k$th row have been removed from the argument minor of the determinant. Therefore in order to swap the other row to its place we need $k - (l + 1)$ (resp. $k - 1 - l$) swaps, so that $$\tag{a} (-1)^{j + l}a'_{lj}\det(A'_{lj}) = (-1)^{j + l + k - (l + 1)}a_{lj}\det(A_{lj})$$ $$\tag{b} (-1)^{j + k}a'_{kj}\det(A'_{kj}) = (-1)^{j + k + k - (l + 1)}a_{kj}\det(A_{kj})$$

**And here's where I'm stuck:**

Since swap of arguments in the determinant constitutes an additional multiplication by $-1$, we only care whether the total number of swaps is even or odd. If in the case of (a) and (b) the total number of additional swaps $k - (l + 1)$ is odd, then we are good to go, as we can simplify the formula (1) to the form $d(A') = -d(A)$. But how to handle the case when $k - (l + 1)$ is even? As then the sign of the other two summands in (1) does not change, so I don't see how the formula could be easily simplified. Moreover, as of writing, I don't see any immediate contradiction if $k - (l + 1)$ is even.

In what, if in any, way can the proof be salvaged?

Comment: Skew symmetric? The determinant is defined to be the *unique* function which is alternating multilinear in all its arguments. The [Leibniz formula for determinants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) satisfies this, and Wikipedia offers a [proof of equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_expansion#Proof) of the Leibniz formula with the cofactors expansion on their page for the cofactor expansion.

Comment: @FShrike By skew symmetricity of a function $f: \mathbb{R}^n\times\dots\times\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ I mean that $f(a_1,\dots,a_i,\dots,a_j,\dots,a_n) = -f(a_1,\dots,a_j,\dots,a_i,\dots, a_n)$. As for the proof of Wikipedia, I'm trying to prove the same theorem myself as I found that proof quite hard (and a bit uninformative) to read.

Answer (score 1):

Excercises 7-9 on page 37 here:
https://mtaylor.web.unc.edu/wp-content/uploads/sites/16915/2018/04/linalg.pdf
sketch the proof. The main step is to prove that
$$\det
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n} \\
0 & a_{22} & \dots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
0 & a_{n2} & \dots & a_{nn} \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\det
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\
0 & a_{22} & \dots & a_{2n} \\
\vdots & \vdots & & \vdots \\
0 & a_{n2} & \dots & a_{nn} \\
\end{pmatrix}
= \det(A_{11}).
$$
The formula follows quickly from this.